# Why does JDOM´s SAXBuilder cause a java.net.SocketException?

Tags: sockets, xhtml, jdom

I have a problem with JDOM 1.1 that i can´t find a solution, let alone a cause for (I´ve searched quite a while...). I have a small test program with a pretty simple setup:

1. Create a new `File` object that already exists and that I´m planning to parse. It´s an `XHTML` file.
2. Create a new `SAXBuilder` with validate set to false
3. Create a new `Document` object, that should be filled by the `SAXBuilder`

**The Problem & My Question**

Somehow, `builder.build(file)` causes a `java.net.SocketException` with message `Permission denied: connect`. I don´t see why it should even need a socket connection, except to validate, which I set to false in the cosntructor of the `SAXBuilder`. So, my question is: Can anyone tell me what could be the cause of that exception? More specifically, where does it try to connect to and how could i prevent it?

Thank you!

**JAVA code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\test.xhtml");
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
try {
  Document document = builder.build(file);
  XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
  outputter.output(document, System.out);
} catch (JDOMException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**The XHTML file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Title of document</title>
</head>

<body>
  some content
</body>

</html>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:637)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1290)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1257)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:489)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:847)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:826)
at test.xmlparser.Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

Comment: As always, writing down the question helped solving it myself shortly after. For those who come across the same issue:

The problem is the first line:
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

simply remove it, e.g. by some pre-processor and the XMLOutputter will replace it with a standard xml declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the DTD is used to validate the XHTML document. As you discovered in your comment.

In XML the DTD is used to not only validate the XHTML document structure, but also to supply any entity references that need to be expanded (think `nbsp;` , etc.).

The reason I am answering this question while knowing you have an answer already, is because your answer is a partial answer, and it is not a good solution. Removing the doctype for an XHTML document is going to cause other problems later on.

Unfortunately, the right solution is to have the DTD documents available for your parser. For standard XML parsing, the typical way is to just pull the DTD from the URL (which is what JDOM is trying to do here - actually xerces is trying to do it as JDOM asks it to parse the document). If you don't have a network connection, that can be really hard, as you have discovered. But, even if you do have a network connection, if th XML is XHTML, you have a double-problem - the W3C folk are intentionally breaking your code!!!

There are some references you should see:

1. [W3C's excessive DTD block](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/)
2. [How to bypass the request to the internet for DTD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html#resolveEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and some instructions on [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipent/)
3. Use a catalog: [XML-Catalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog)
4. A small project I started a while back that "behaves well" and caches documents: [Resolver](https://github.com/rolfl/Resolver) <-- that won't be very useful to you because you have no network, but it has some documentation about the problem.

If you have an idea of how you want to resolve the DTD, you can then supply the EntityResolver to the JDOM SAXBuilder with: [`setEntityResolver()`](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder.html#setEntityResolver(org.xml.sax.EntityResolver))